# Replace words in string by multiple scans

Tags: ruby

My goal is to turn any two consecutive commas into `",NA,"`. This means that:

1. `str = ",,,123,,BLAH,,"` changes to `",NA,123,NA,BLAH,NA,"`
2. `",,,"` changes to `",NA,NA,"`
3. `",,,,"` changes to `",NA,NA,NA,"`
4. `",blah,,hi,"` changes to `",blah,NA,hi,"`

There could be anywhere between 1 and 100,000 commas in the strings with any number of characters between the commas. My code is:

```
str = str.gsub!(",,",",NA,")
# => ",NA,123,NABLAH,NA"
```

I am running into issues because it needs to happen multiple times. If I repeat the `gsub` multiple times, I hit an error `undefined method gsub! for nil class` because `gsub` returns the result, yet if there is no substitution, it returns `nil`.

Comment: What about odd numbers of commas, as in your first example, which has three?

Comment: You change the question and then, in the face of a new comment asking for clarification, you immediately select an answer???  Moreover, the select answer results in `",,".gsub(",","NA,") #=> "NA,NA,", which contradicts your question update!

Comment: The downvote and vote to close are mine, for the question being unclear. There is *prima facie* evidence for this. You said each pair of commas is to be converted to `,NA,`. The simplest possible string we can apply that to is `',,'` (two commas only), which should become `',NA,'`, yet the answer you selected does not do that.

Comment: Cary, The Note I included in my original code (inside the code block) specified that I did not know what the string would look like. I later added the Update section to my code to make it even more obvious. I apologize if I confused you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ruby > ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,".gsub(",",",NA")
=> ",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA"
```

or alternately:

```
 ruby > ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,".gsub(",","NA,")
 => "NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"
```

**edit**: To handle the use case better (didn't quite get original question):

```
2.2.0 :004 > str=",,,123,,BLAH,,"
 => ",,,123,,BLAH,," 
2.2.0 :005 > str.split(",")
 => ["", "", "", "123", "", "BLAH"] 
2.2.0 :006 > str.split(",").map{|x|x.length == 0 ? "NA" : x}.join(",")
 => "NA,NA,NA,123,NA,BLAH"
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but that doesnt work for this case: ",,,,hi,,". It leaves me with: ",NA,NAhi,NA" (note the lack of space between hi and NA)

Answer (score 0):

According to your use-case (",,,123,,BLAH,," turning into ",NA,123,NA,BLAH,NA,") I'm assuming you want **all** commas between characters to turn into ,NA,?

This is easily done using regular expressions with gsub.

```
str=",,,123,,BLAH,,"
str.gsub!(/,+/,",NA,") #returns ",NA,123,NA,BLAH,NA,"
```

the regular expression `/,+/` is matching 'one or more' commas